# Problems installing LYNC on non-domain controler

Tags: active-directory, lync

I have two servers in this set up. AD and EX, the domain is called mydomain.net

- The AD is a Windows 2008 Server (32 bit) with Active Directory
  installed
- AD only has it's own ip in the DNS-servers list
- AD.mydomain.net does resolve correctly in the dns
- EX is a Windows 2008 R2 that is connected to the mydomain.net-domain
- EX only DNS server is the ip of the ad.mydomain.net
- There are no firewalls running between the two servers

When trying to install Lync 2010 on the EX server I get the following error
"Not available :Failure occurred attempting to check the schema state.Please ensure Active Directory is reachable."

I can control the AD from EX, also login to it and do successful checks like

```
netdom query /domain:mydomain.net fsmo
```

...that resolves correctly

I suspect there is something fundamentally wrong with my setup, maybe Lync need a 2k8 R2 ad?

Comment: Seems as if I made a typo, but all firewalls are down

Comment: Lync requires schema extension. Have you defined a site in sites and services and associated the subnet to it? You also need to run the setup as a user with rights to perform a schema upgrade.

Comment: Oh and if you plan to make Lync accessible externally you will need a third server unless you plan to use VPN. You may also run into collisions in IIS here.

Comment: Where do I start with Schema extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to obtain and run the extadsch.exe from the Microsoft System Center 2012 Configuration Manager on my Domain Controller.

Comment: Interesting, but I have never had to use a different product to install Lync. I sincerely hope this is a test environment. You're collocating too many functions.

Comment: It is for testing and development. Im setting up a local environment since it would be to risky to develop with the production environment.

Comment: @Trikks Still. Ever since virtualization is around. A 32gb memory server for dev virtual machines costs nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error but I was successful to resolve this issue. Actually you are login as a local user, Please log in to server as a user which is defined in your active directory server in such a way user@domian.